# Fail to feed forward 1D signal to 1D convolution in Keras

Tags: keras

I am newbie of Keras. I want to perform 1D convolution, given a input array. How should I do it? I have write the code but it cannot run

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model

input = np.array(tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))   
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(1,3,strides=1,padding='same', name='conv'))

layer_model = Model(inputs=input,outputs=model.get_layer('conv').output)
conv_output = layer_model.predict(f)    
print (conv_output)
```

This is error

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-31db6e7dcb90> in <module>()
     10 
     11 layer_model = Model(inputs=input,
---> 12                                 outputs=model.get_layer('conv').output)
     13 conv_output = layer_model.predict(f)
     14 print (conv_output)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in output(self)
    808         if not self._inbound_nodes:
    809             raise AttributeError('Layer ' + self.name +
--> 810                                  ' has no inbound nodes.')
    811         if len(self._inbound_nodes) > 1:
    812             raise AttributeError('Layer ' + self.name +

AttributeError: Layer conv has no inbound nodes.
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot run? What error message do you get? Please add all those details. Also you seem to be mixing the Functional and Sequential API, and this won't work.

Comment: Hi. I have update the code and the error. Could you look at it help me?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't complicate yourself by mixing the Functional and Sequential APIs, a simpler way is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D
import numpy as np

input = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
input = input.reshape(1, 8, 1) # (samples, width, channels)   

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(1,3,padding='same', input_shape=(8, 1)))

conv_output = model.predict(input)    
print(conv_output)
```

Note that we haven't set the convolutional weights, so they are automatically initialized to random values.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Could you tell me how to print the weight of the conv that i can verify by hand?